# How to optimize the python code written using regex and for loops?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, pandas, optimization

I have two lists and I need to perform a string match. I have used three for loops and re.pattern to solve. I am getting the expected using existing code (**part1**), but I need to optimized the code (**part2**) as it takes a longer time when I apply for lengthy data.

**part1**

```
texts = ['foo abc', 'foobar xyz', 'xyz baz32', 'baz 45','fooz','bazzar','foo baz']
terms = ['foo','baz','apple']

output_list = []
for term in terms:
    pattern_term = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format(term)
    try:
        for i in range(len(texts)):
            line_text = texts[i]
            for match in re.finditer(pattern_term, line_text):
                start_index = match.start()
                output_list.append([i, start_index, line_text[start_index:], term])
    except:
        pass
```

output:
Explaination fo columns names :

`Index` = index of `texts` when pattern matches

`Start_index` = start index where pattern matches inside text

`Match_text` = complete text of that matching

`Match_term` = term with it matches

```
pd.DataFrame(output_list, columns = ['Index', 'Start_index', 'Match_text', 'Match_term'])

Index   Start_index     Match_text  Match_term
0   0   0   foo abc     foo
1   6   0   foo baz     foo
2   3   0   baz 45      baz
3   6   4   baz         baz
```

---

I have tried the following code (***part2***), but its output is partial:

***part 2***

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Match_text': texts})
pat = r'\b(?:{})\b'.format('|'.join(terms))
df[df['Match_text'].str.contains(pat)]
```

output

```
    Match_text
0   foo abc
3   baz 45
6   foo baz
```

Comment: Sorry, which part of code do you want to speed up? `df[df['Match_text'].str.contains(pat)]`? Or the one before?

Comment: Part 1, mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is already good since you need to find occurrences of whole words inside longer strings, and you create the regex pattern before the loop where the texts are processed with the regex.

The regex already is good, the only thing about it is the redundant non-capturing group that you may discard because you check term by term, there is no alternation inside the group. You might also compile the regex:

```
pattern_term = re.compile(r'\b{}\b'.format(term))
```

Then, you may get rid of temporary variables in the for loop:

```
for i in range(len(texts)):
    for match in pattern_term.finditer(texts[i]):
        output_list.append([i, match.start(), texts[i][match.start():], term])
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the solution, unfortunately, I don't see any difference in elapsed time.